# Need suggestion for web crawler software to help build a database of accountants

Tags: database, web-crawler

We are working on simplifying accounting, payables and invoicing. In order to get the accountant to use our product we are intending to use email marketing targeted exclusively to all the book-keepers and accounting/CPA firms in USA. We will like to know whether there is any software/application that will help to crawl the net and get email id of the target market. Like say we can use terms like CPA or accountants and the software/application will help to pull relevant email ids to us.

Please let us know whether this can be done.

Regards
Niladri C

Comment: This can be done. Google does a fine job of it. Why build an app for something you can do with a Web query?

Comment: One other comment: If you're planning to do a mass cold mailing based on addresses you found on the same Web pages as words like "CPA" or "accountant" then this is highly antisocial and deplorable. This kind of abuse of the Internet is making it worse for the rest of us. I hope your business fails.

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously consider purchasing a commercial company directory. Most companies providing these services can provide you with Excel, CSV or XML files which you can easily iterate with your desired scripting language.

Not only will you have more prospects faster, chances are you will not get listings for companies who do not want to be targeted by direct-mail marketing, which is a wish that should be respected.

Right now you are setting yourself up for spam-complaints, which could result in your email domain or server getting blacklisted. Think carefully before choosing your strategy.

Comment: @ carL Smotricz : we are trying to develop an application that will make it easy for the accountants to perform their day-to-day task and they can download it for free. So I think we are not trying to do anything seriously wrong here

Comment: @beginning_steps : The nature of the application you are offering is irrelevant. Like Carl said, a mass cold mailing is considered antisocial. 
Try getting coverage in blogs and social media. Make a quality product and get people to talk about it online. If your application really provides something worthwile, word will spread. 
Lots of people nowadays do not tolerate unsollicited emails, let alone read them or click thru to a website with a 'free' product.
If you advertise 'free', people will think there's a catch.

Comment: @ Symen : Thanks a lot for your guidance, we will surely try to incorporate these advice in spreading the words about our product. Just thought that email marketing will help us in drill-down to the right audience real quick.

Comment: @beginning_steps : Don't underestimate the power of picking up the phone to telephone a small part of your target audience. If they let you demo some things over the phone, you could receive valuable feedback about the first impression your product makes.